# Java graphical glitch in console application in cmd but not in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been working on a currency converter in Java for school, but it doesn't work correctly when executed from cmd. I have recompiled it multiple times, but it just doesn't work. It works fine when using the eclipse console, but not in the default windows cmd. I am asking because I cannot find an answer. I don't know if it's how I've coded it so I will post a screenshot and the part of the code that doesn't work. The rest of the program displays fine.

Image of glitch :

[image: Image of glitch]

The first question mark is supposed to be a '1' and the second line is supposed to be '2) Convert GBP to USD' in between these lines it's supposed to say 'Or'.

```
String tmpWWCN = IO.input("Do you want to:\n1)Convert " + names.get(nameIndex).split("2")[0] + " to " + cn2.get(nameIndex) + "?\nOr 2) Convert " + cn2.get(nameIndex) + " to " + names.get(nameIndex).split("2")[0]);
```

Sorry that I can't post the full code. It is stretched across the whole program. (About 120 lines)

UPDATE:
Tried without \n and \r\n (gives same effect) and now it is giving me yet another graphical glitch. I'll post screenshot:

New Glitch:

[image: Image of New Glitch]

Exact same code but without \n or \r\n

Comment: which class are you using to print to the console?

Comment: Custom class called  IO. Simply takes the first argument and passes it to System.out.println. Input does the same thing but uses a buffered reader to gain input after printing the question. Returns input.

Comment: Just to be sure, could you just replace "IO.input" with "System.out.println" and check that it gives the same output ?

Comment: Same glitch using System.out.println

Comment: What kind of system are you using? Windows, Linux? Perhaps there is something weird going on when you use '\n'. I know different systems can act differently, but I have never seen this kind of behaviour though. Try useing '\r\n' instead.

Comment: I'm using windows 7 at school.

Comment: @cvesters Tried \r\n same effect. I'm just going to remove the \n. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm real noob in java, but I was thinking what if you cut your string into lines as it should be in program?

Like this:

```
String tmpWWCN = IO.input("Do you want to:\n" + "1)Convert " + names.get(nameIndex).split("2")[0] + " to " + cn2.get(nameIndex) + "?\n" + "Or 2) Convert " + cn2.get(nameIndex) + " to " + names.get(nameIndex).split("2")[0]);
```

Comment: I've got no idea what you have changed. It looks the exact same.

Comment: Oh I see. Don't think that'll fix it though. Even without newlines glitch still happens.

Comment: Tricky problem. You said earlier that you want 'Or' between the lines. I noticed you are missing \n after Or.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that. I have a though that it is because our schools 'Tech Support' can't even set up java or eclipse. I ask for a java compiler they give me a java EE compiler. Also the laptop they give me for doing university A level work is an I3 ._.